# How to add multiple text fields to 'fields_for' in has_many, belongs_to relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a rails application. I am supposed to implement `has_many`, `belong_to` relations between `Author`, and `Location` models as follows, and wrote something as:

In models:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
end
```

In location/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@location) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :location_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :location_name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :authors do |a| %>      
    <%= a.label :name %>
    <%= a.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My question is, even the location can have many authors, it is showing only one text field for author for the `fields_for :authors`, **then how can I achieve to append as many as text fields for authors according to the user wish?**

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beautiful tutorial from Ryan Bates:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. I want to append as many as text fields for authors. Means I want to put a `add` & `remove` links beside every text fields for authors.

Comment: sorry, my first answer was in direct to your question: how can you achieve to append as many as text fields for authors according to the user wish. )

Comment: Thank you very much Valery, my application is going well.

Comment: @VenkatK, have you found a way to add `add` & `remove` links?