# Nesting forms in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following Models

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end
```

On the create question page I want to be able to create 4 answers for the question on the same page. How would I lay this out?

Answer (score 0):

This is not dissimilar to other posts on the subject of nested form objects:

[How to add multiple text fields to 'fields_for' in has_many, belongs_to relations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133592/how-to-add-multiple-text-fields-to-fields-for-in-has-many-belongs-to-relation)

For brevity, the accepted answer to the post above suggests viewing the following posts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Answer (score 0):

In question.rb:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
```

For the form:

```
= form_for @question do |q|
  = fields_for @question.answers do |a|
    = a.label :answer_attr, "Label"
    = a.text_area :answer_attr
```

This is the basic way to use nested forms. There will be some javascript needed to be able to add new answers. You should checkout this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised), it is all about nested forms.